# How to parse date time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have Date in this format `mm/dd/yy`  example: `04/11/13`
and time in the format `HH:MM:SS`        example: `17:02:30`

I have to parse above two values and put in a variable `dateTime` with following format

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSS

2013-04-11T17:02:30.000
```

What is best way to do it in AngularJS or in Javascript. I also need to verify the user input and make sure it is a valid `mm/dd/yy` date and a valid `HH:MM:SS` time

I know there are tons of duplicate/similar questions but I couldn't find one which answers above, please let me know if you found one.

Comment: creating filter is the best way to do it

Comment: Might worth considering moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal Can you provide any code example?

Comment: @mishik, I have looked into momentjs. Isn't that good for manipulating date-time not for this parsing. Can you provide some code example.

Comment: `moment("<your_date>", "<your_date_format>").format("<format_needed>")`
e.g.: `moment("04/11/13 17:02:30", "MM/DD/YY HH:mm:ss").format()`
The default "format()" seems like what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need an external library to do this. See [this doc link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for the forms of date that JavaScript can process normally.

For a specific solution to your question:

```
var date = new Date("04/11/13" + " " + "17:02:30");
date.toISOString();
>> "2013-04-11T21:02:30.000Z"
```

See [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info on the Date object.

Comment: +1. This is great! BTW, this is for another problem is there a way quick way using the same API to convert the resultant `Z` zulu time back to user's local time-zone?

Comment: Yep! Since when we initially created the Date object we didn't specify the time offset, JavaScript automatically uses the local user's timezone. To get the time in the user's local time we could do something like `date.toLocaleTimeString("ca-8601")` which will return `"17:02:30"`.

Comment: Additionally you can specify the timezone in the date string e.g. `new Date("2014 Jul 21 GMT+0530 07:51:00")`

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this in AngularJS is with a filter. You bind to the dateTime, and then filter it with the date filter.

```
<span>{{myDate | date:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sss}}</span>
```

Or in your controller you say:

```
$filter('date')(date[, format])
```

Here is more info: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Comment: Although this function is very useful, it is not relevant for this question which is about parsing the date.